# Is there a viewstate event before postback?

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate, listboxitems

Consider the following: A text value added to a textbox on the client is added to viewstate on postback (thus the value is still present in the textbox when the page has reloaded).

How come when I move a value from listbox1 to listbox2 via jquery the items in listbox2 are not added to viewstate. (note: the items are selected before POST and the values in listbox2 are available on the server on postback via request.form.getvalues("listbox2").getvalue(index).tostring())

I'm not looking for a work around, I've got that. I'm want to know "why" the listbox2 values are not added. Is there some event being fired for the textbox but not the listbox?  Just trying to better understand what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A text value added to a textbox on the client is added to viewstate on postback (thus the value is still present in the textbox when the page has reloaded).

This statement is incorrect. The value of a `TextBox` server control is preserved across postbacks because the browser sends it in the post data, and on postback the `TextBox` copies the value from the post data to its `Text` property. View state is not involved, as you can verify by setting `EnableViewState="False"`. (I'm assuming here that the `TextBox` is visible and enabled; otherwise, the browser *doesn't* sent its value in the post data, and view state *is* required to preserve the value.)

> How come when I move a value from listbox1 to listbox2 via jquery the items in listbox2 are not added to viewstate.

For a multi-selection `ListBox` server control, the browser sends the value of each selected item in the post data. On postback, the `ListBox` looks at each value in the post data, searches for the corresponding item in its `Items` collection, and sets that item's `Selected` property to `True`. It doesn't add unrecognized values to the `Items` collection; instead, if event validation is enabled, it throws an "Invalid postback or callback argument" exception. Again, view state is not involved.

Comment: why are items added to listbox2 on the client (via jquery) not available in the Items collection on the server?

Comment: The `ListBox` control wasn't designed by the ASP.NET team to automatically add dynamically created items to the `Items` collection. (As I noted in the last paragraph, it throws an exception instead, because it assumes a malicious user is attempting to tamper with the post data.) You could create your own `ListBox` control that does so, but you'd only have the *value* of each item, because the browser doesn't send the option text.